# Change Processing API level to use lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8, processing

I've the below code snippet in Processing 3.3.6:

`menuBarButtons.add(new TextButton("File", 0, 0, 20, menuBarHeight, (() -> println("Test")) ));`

However, processing gives the error

`Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above`

This is quite easy to fix in any normal java IDE by changing the JRE in the build path/run configuration, but I can't find any option for this in the settings. I tried copy pasting a more up to date JRE into the processing folder, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

As of right now, the Processing editor does not support Java 8 syntax. More info [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Supported-Platforms#java-versions).

If you really need Java 8 syntax, you can always use [Processing as a Java library](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) from another IDE, where you can use Java 8 if you want to.